# pg_dump: error: no matching tables were found

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Given the following Postgres container:

```
docker run -i -p 54350:5432 --name test_postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password -e POSTGRES_DB=test -e POSTGRES_SCHEMA=dba postgres:11 "-clog_statement=all"
```

and the following init sql script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS dba;

CREATE TABLE dba.mytable (mytable_id SERIAL);
```

When running `\dt` in `psql` I get:

```
psql -U postgres -h localhost -p 54350 -d test

test=# \dt dba.mytable
             List of relations
 Schema |     Name      | Type  |  Owner
--------+---------------+-------+----------
 dba    | mytable       | table | postgres
(1 row)

test=#
```

But when I attempt to run `pg_dump`, I get the following:

```
pg_dump \
    --username=postgres --host=localhost --port=54350 --dbname=test \
    --schema-only \
    --no-privileges \
    --disable-triggers \
    --no-publications \
    --no-security-labels \
    --no-subscriptions \
    --no-synchronized-snapshots \
    --quote-all-identifiers \
    -t=dba.mytable > dump.sql
Password:
pg_dump: error: no matching tables were found
```

I also tried with `-t='"dba.mytable"'` and `-t="dba.mytable"`.

I also tried with `-t=test.dba.mytable`, `-t='"test.dba.mytable"'` and `-t="test.dba.mytable"`, but then I get

```
pg_dump: error: cross-database references are not implemented: test.dba
```

If I add `--schema=dba` I get:

```
pg_dump: error: no matching schemas were found
```

Can you help me fix my pg_dump command so as to allow me to dump the table `dba.mytable`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused between long and short options. The documentation says:

```
-t pattern
--table=pattern
```

That means that `pg_dump` is looking for a table called `=dba.mytable`, which explains the error message. Use

```bash
pg_dump -t dba.mytable
```

or

```bash
pg_dump --table=dba.mytable
```

Comment:  ... That solves it - thanks a lot Laurenz!
Now I wish that the error printed would have been more verbose; that would have saved me a good hour and a half!